# Console showing undefined when displaying the properties of a existing object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, javascript-objects

```js
var errors = validationResult(req);

console.log("errors: errors");

if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
  res.render('signIn-signUp', {
    'error1': errors.msg + " " + errors.value + " Please signUp again!!"
  });
} else {
  var id = 0;
  pool.query("Select Max(C_Id) as C_Id from customer", function(error, rows) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("Database error: ", error);
          res.render('signIn-signUp', {
            'error1': "database error: " + error + "please sign up again!"
          });
```

The above code is part of a nodeJs codebase.
In the above code snippet, when I log errors object on console, it shows all the properties as:

```
errors: [{
  value: 'a',
  msg: 'Must be at least 5 char long',
  param: 'Password',
  location: 'body'
}]
```

but, when I display the individual properties of the object on the console, it is showing it as undefined.
That is, console.log(errors.msg) is returning undefined. What is the reason for that?

How can I display the properties which exist in the object and are not undefined?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `errors` object is an array (hence the `[]`). Try this:

```
    console.log(errors[0].msg);
```

Comment: I tried it, but it gave error: (TypeError: Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined)

Comment: where in your code did you try `console.log(errors);` (which returns the object), and where did you try `console.log(errors[0].msg);` (which failed)?

Comment: console.log(errors[0].msg) gave a error. The error is (TypeError: Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined)

Comment: yes, but in which part of your code are you trying that? could you edit your question so we know where exactly you inserted console.log(errors); and console.log(errors[0].msg);? (e.g. as comment in the code)